# Azure B2C Tenant wise User management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am referring following example : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/

I have created main (physical) Azure B2C Tenant, in that I am managing virtual tenant.

```
 e.g. Azure B2C Tenant (Main)
         - Virtual tenant in Storage table 
           - Tenant 1
           - Tenant 2 etc.
```

But I have single AD and I want to separate the user based on Tenant.

How can I achieve this with Role base user management for tenant ?

Answer (score 0):

**Role based user management is yet not supported in Azure AD B2C.** I would recommend you request this in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).

I can think of two options for you:

1. **Use a [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) to assign users their "tenant"**. You would then need to make sure you set this custom attribute via the [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet). You can then include this claim in your token and use it in your application to drive behavior.
2. **Define Azure AD groups that map to "tenants"**. However, given that in Azure AD B2C, groups are not included in the claims, you won't be able to do what's [recommended for Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/), instead, you will need to query the [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to retrieve the [user's group membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersMemberships) and drive behavoir from that.

Comment: My confusion is, I have AAD 'X' , now customer is register to tenant 1 and same customer is going to register for tenant 2 with the same email id, how AAD will allow to register same type of user in two different tenants but in single AAD

Comment: Following my recommendation, you would only have the user in Azure AD B2C once, and you'd have 2 values in you "tenants" custom attribute or the user would belong to two Azure AD groups; one for each tenant.

Comment: I am using azure functions and need to make call to Microsoft Graph, I have registered my endpoint in AAD, other then B2C. How can I achieve this ? Is it right way ?